# Parallel processing in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java2

I writed a demo code to use Parallel processing in RxJava :

```
Flowable.range(1, 10)
            .flatMap(v ->
                    Flowable.just(v)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                            .map(w -> w)
            )
            .blockingSubscribe(integer -> {
                System.out.println(integer+" thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            });
```

According to the document "Practically, parallelism in RxJava means running independent flows and merging their results back into a single flow. The operator flatMap does this by first mapping each number from 1 to 10 into its own individual Flowable, runs them and merges the computed squares." but but I do not know exactly how Rxjava performs that when the result returned is all done on a thread. The result I got was

```
1 thread : 1
2 thread : 1
3 thread : 1
4 thread : 1
7 thread : 1
6 thread : 1
5 thread : 1
10 thread : 1
9 thread : 1
8 thread : 1
```

Can someone explain how rxjava has done this to produce the same result as if only one thread was used? Thanks for advance!!!

Comment: Isn't the `println` running on the main thread, separate from all the flows?

Comment: "merging the results back into a single flow." The protocol requires that subscribers are notified non-overlappingly and `blockingSubscribe` also ensures it calls the lambas from the thread initiated the subscription. Hence you see that the result of the parallel computation will be delivered on one thread.

Comment: Thank you @akarnokd and Jim Garrison . I have resolved my question!